# react-scroll won't scroll to specific element with explicit id

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a file called `Terms.js` that has 2 checkboxes at the end of some scrollable text inside a container. I'm trying to use `react-scroll` to smooth scroll to one of those checkboxes using [this video guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zS6zo-iboEo). When I use:

```
<a className="checkbox-scroll-link" href="#checkbox-scroll-tag">
    {termsandconditions.mobileScrollPromptText}
</a>
```

It will correctly jump to the checkbox. But when I use `<Link>` like in `{/* -------------- Bottom Section -------------- */}` of my code below, it doesn't find/scroll to the checkbox.

This is how I'm importing it in `Terms.js`:

`import { Link } from 'react-scroll';`

Here is how I'm rendering the component inside `Terms.js`:

```
render() {
const bgStyle = {
  backgroundImage: `url(${loginCampus})`,
};
const mainContent = (
  <div id="terms-page">
    <div className="background-container" style={bgStyle}>
      <div className="overlay-container">
        <div className="terms-container">
          {/* -------------- Top Section -------------- */}
          <div className="columns top-section-container is-multiline is-mobile">
            <div className="column top-left">
              <div className="back-container">
                <img
                  src={arrow}
                  className="back-button"
                  onClick={this.routeBack}
                  onKeyDown={this.routeBack}
                  alt="back"
                  role="presentation"
                />
                <p
                  className="back-text"
                  onClick={this.routeBack}
                  onKeyDown={this.routeBack}
                  role="presentation"
                >
                  Back
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="column is-half header-text-container has-text-centered">
              <h1>{termsandconditions.header1}</h1>
              <h2>{termsandconditions.header2}</h2>
            </div>
            <div className="column"></div>
          </div>
          <div className="yellow-horizontal-line"></div>
          <div className="footer-horizontal-line-container">
            <div className="grey-horizontal-line"></div>
          </div>
          {/* -------------- Middle Section -------------- */}
          <div className="text-box">
            <div className="columns is-multiline is-centered">
              <div className="column is-full">
                <p>{termsandconditions.termstext}</p>
              </div>
              <div className="column is-narrow">
                <label className="checkbox">
                  <input type="checkbox" onChange={this.handleTermsCheck} />
                  <span className="checkbox-text" id="checkbox-scroll-tag">
                    {termsandconditions.checkbox1}
                  </span>
                </label>
              </div>
              <div className="column is-narrow"></div>
              <div className="column is-narrow">
                <label className="checkbox">
                  <input type="checkbox" onChange={this.handleAgeCheck} />
                  <span className="checkbox-text">
                    {termsandconditions.checkbox2}
                  </span>
                </label>
              </div>
              <div className="column"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          {/* -------------- Bottom Section -------------- */}
          <div className="footer">
            <div className="mobile-scroll-prompt">
              <Link
                className="checkbox-scroll-link"
                to="checkbox-scroll-tag"
                smooth={true}
                duration={1000}
              >
                {termsandconditions.mobileScrollPromptText}
              </Link>
            </div>
            <div className="footer-horizontal-line-container">
              <div className="grey-horizontal-line"></div>
            </div>
            <button
              className="button agree-button"
              disabled={!this.state.allTermsAgreed}
              onClick={this.goToGameExamplePage}
            >
              Agree
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
);
return <section className="section auth">{mainContent}</section>;}}
```

Comment: I tried that @chrisbyte but it didn't work either

Comment: Based on the docs, `react-scroll` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scroll) is using an internal implementation of `<Link>` which does support hashes natively (https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Link/to-object) but it doesn't pass through here. You have to use a click event to scroll to an element. There are some examples here https://github.com/fisshy/react-scroll/blob/master/examples/with-hash/app.js the anchor one is `test6`